# How can I create temporary records of Linq-To-Sql types without causing duplicate key problems?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have code that generates records based on my DataGridView. These records are temporary because some of them already exist in the database.

```
        Crop_Variety v = new Crop_Variety();
        v.Type_ID = currentCropType.Type_ID;
        v.Variety_ID = r.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        v.Description = r.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        v.Crop = currentCrop;
        v.Crop_ID = currentCrop.Crop_ID;
```

Unfortunately in this little bit of code, because I say that v.Crop = currentCrop,
now currentCrop.Crop_Varieties includes this temporary record. And when I go to insert the records of this grid that are new, they have a reference to the same Crop record, and therefore these temporary records that do already exist in the database show up twice causing duplicate key errors when I submit.

I have a whole system for detecting what records need to be added and what need to be deleted based on what the user has done, but its getting gummed up by this relentless tracking of references.

Is there a way I can stop Linq-To-Sql from automatically adding these temporary records to its table collections?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why you create new `Crop_Variety` instances but don't want them to be persisted. Or do you want L2S to find out which are the duplicates before persisting them?

Comment: I'm trying to create instances for all the records found in the DataGridView. Not all of the data has a straight forward mapping to the datagridview, so I wasn't sure if I could do any sort of automatic updating / inserting.

I am totally reorganzing my save-code because this issue keeps coming up in my current system but if there was a better way to identify existing records and new records while processing the grid row data that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest revisiting the code that populates DataGridView (grid) with records.

And then revisit the code that operates on items from a GridView, keeping in mind that you can grab bound item from a grid row using the following code:

```
public object GridSelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            if (_grid == null || _grid.SelectedCells.Count < 1) return null;
            DataGridViewCell cell = _grid.SelectedCells[0];
            DataGridViewRow row = _grid.Rows[cell.RowIndex];
            if (row.DataBoundItem == null) return null;
            return row.DataBoundItem;
        }
        catch { }
        return null; 
    }
}
```

It is also hard to understand the nature of Crop_Variety code that you have posted. As the Crop_Variety seems to be a subclass of Crop. This leads to problems when the Crop is not yet bound to database and potentially lead to problems when you're adding Crop_Variety to the context.

For this type of Form application I normally have List _dataList inside form class, then the main grid is bound to that list, through ObjectBindingList or another way. That way _dataList holds all data that needs to be persisted when needed (user clicked save).

Comment: That sounds like it will work. My example with Crop_Variety isn't really relevant anymore so I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign an entity object reference you are creating a link between the two objects. Here you are doing that:

```
v.Crop = currentCrop;
```

There is only one way to avoid this: Modify the generated code or generate/write your own. I would never do this.

I think you will be better off by writing a custom DTO class instead of reusing the generated entities. I have done both approaches and I like the latter one far better.

Edit: Here is some sample generated code:

```
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="RssFeed_RssFeedItem", Storage="_RssFeed", ThisKey="RssFeedID", OtherKey="ID", IsForeignKey=true, DeleteOnNull=true, DeleteRule="CASCADE")]
    public RssFeed RssFeed
    {
        get
        {
            return this._RssFeed.Entity;
        }
        set
        {
            RssFeed previousValue = this._RssFeed.Entity;
            if (((previousValue != value) 
                        || (this._RssFeed.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
            {
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                if ((previousValue != null))
                {
                    this._RssFeed.Entity = null;
                    previousValue.RssFeedItems.Remove(this);
                }
                this._RssFeed.Entity = value;
                if ((value != null))
                {
                    value.RssFeedItems.Add(this);
                    this._RssFeedID = value.ID;
                }
                else
                {
                    this._RssFeedID = default(int);
                }
                this.SendPropertyChanged("RssFeed");
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see the generated code is establishing the link by saying "value.RssFeedItems.Add(this);".

In case you have many entities for wich you would need many DTOs you could code-generate the DTO classes by using reflection.